# What is this content returned (expecting sourceMap)?

Tags: python, algorand

I've set up my Algorand node and enabled the sourceMap return on compile! I'm using the Python SDK.

However, if I try to print the response of the function `compileTeal(program, Mode.Application, version=TEAL_VERSION)`, I get this:

`'sourcemap': {'version': 3, 'sources': [], 'names': [], 'mapping': ';;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;AACA;;AACA;AACA;AACA;;;AACA;;AACA;AACA`...

What does this mean? I expected the offset list.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's VLQ encoded.

As of today, the decoder isn't released. But there is a fix here that you can use - https://github.com/algorand/py-algorand-sdk/pull/353